# CakePHP Configure::Write() + Reference

Tags: php, cakephp

My core configuration is pulling in an external include that contains an array that I'm more or less using (for lack of a better word) as a heap to track state information between cake and my back end libraries.

Since the heap will change with some frequency, is it possible to use Configure::write() or something similar to assign a config var as a reference to this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you did something like:

```
Configure::write('IncludeFileRef', 'my_include.php');
```

And then to reference the file:

```
$file = Configure::read('IncludeFileRef');
include_once($file);
```

I think that will work.

**UPDATE:**
Or, if you need to reference the array:

```
Configure::write('array_ref', 'my_array');
```

And then to reference the array:

```
$array = ${Configure::read('array_ref')};
```